# AWS IoT Core, project working in local. When deploy raising an error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, cloud, iot

I am getting data from aws iot core via subscribing to a topic. This works fine in local computer. However, when I deployed it in render I am encountering an error when subscribing to the topic. But I can see the value from the device is going through the aws iot core monitoring. But when I open the deployed project it cannot subscribe to the topic, below is the error:

```
raise subscribeTimeoutException()
Aug 25 11:36:57 PM  AWSIoTPythonSDK.exception.AWSIoTExceptions.subscribeTimeoutException
```

I have also been researching and others saying I need to edit the policy. I already did but nothing changed

Tried changing the policy.
`Action = "iot:*"`

Comment: Subscribe timed out
Aug 25 11:47:33 PM  [2023-08-25 15:47:33,188] ERROR in app: Exception on /_dash-update-component [POST]
Aug 25 11:47:33 PM  Traceback (most recent call last):
Aug 25 11:47:33 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2529, in wsgi_app
Aug 25 11:47:33 PM      response = self.full_dispatch_request()
Aug 25 11:47:33 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1825, in full_dispatch_request
Aug 25 11:47:33 PM      rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

Comment: Aug 25 11:47:33 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1823, in full_dispatch_request
Aug 25 11:47:33 PM      rv = self.dispatch_request()
Aug 25 11:47:33 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
Aug 25 11:47:33 PM      return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
Aug 25 11:47:33 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 1264, in dispatch
Aug 25 11:47:33 PM      ctx.run(

Comment: Aug 25 11:47:33 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dash/_callback.py", line 437, in add_context
Aug 25 11:47:33 PM      output_value = func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)  # %% callback invoked %%
Aug 25 11:47:33 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/src/app.py", line 153, in update_output
Aug 25 11:47:33 PM      myAWSIoTMQTTClient.subscribe(wincc_Level_Tag, 1, customCallback)

Comment: Aug 25 11:47:33 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/AWSIoTPythonSDK/MQTTLib.py", line 703, in subscribe
Aug 25 11:47:33 PM      return self._mqtt_core.subscribe(topic, QoS, callback)
Aug 25 11:47:33 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/AWSIoTPythonSDK/core/protocol/mqtt_core.py", line 306, in subscribe
Aug 25 11:47:33 PM      raise subscribeTimeoutException()

Comment: Thank you in advance guys, I hope someone can help with this matter.